# python: How to run command on local machine from an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to automate the process of creating a postgres database from production dump using a python script. I am running this script on an EC2 instance that hosts an RoR app server.

I am able to create the DB using psychopg. But in the same script I want to do the following:

```
- do a deploy using capistrano from local machine
```

I came across paramiko - SSHClient in my research. I think it can be used. But I'm not sure how I can SSH from an EC2 instance to my local machine.
I found out my IP(say a.b.c.d) and tried `ssh a.b.c.d` from the EC2 instance but it says:

```
ssh: connect to host a.b.c.d port 22: Connection refused
```

So my question is:
- If this method (using paramiko) is correct, how can I set up a ssh connection from EC2 instance to my local machine
OR
If paramiko cannot achieve this, how can I run the deploy from my script that is on the EC2 instance

Comment: You can set a reverse ssh tunneling (google it ;))

Answer (score 1):

For one, paramiko is a bit low-level, you could try using [Fabric](http://fabfile.org), it will make a lot of things much easier.

Secondly, check whether your local machine is

- accessible from the internet, i.e. has public IP address
- running SSH (assuming you run *NIX-like OS, run `ps -ef | grep sshd`,
  if you see a process matching, then you should be able to connect)

Then, if you wanna automate a postgres DB creation *on* a EC2 instance, why do you need a connection from it to your local machine. Wouldn't it be more logical to reverse the process? I.e. SSH *from* local machine to EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for a very useful answer. Regarding your 3rd point : when I started writing the script, I didn't realize that I'll have to add the deploy feature. Since the DB was required in the EC2 I wrote the script in the EC2. Surprisingly the same script soesn't work on my local machine. Not sure why

Comment: Cause your local machine doesn't run SSH I suppose? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I just checked using the command you mentioned. Its showing running processes. I'm using ubuntu 12.04